# React-Native APK still running in dev mode

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I have finished developing a small app for Android using React-Native. Comes the bundling process, which according to the documentation goes as follows (With dev set to false):

```
sudo react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Then assemling my release:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Signing the app, zipaligning it and there comes my final APK.
But then, when my Bugsnag library catches an error I notice this in the 
stacktrace of the error:

```
at Object.touchableHandlePress (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:29456
```

Where I clearly see that dev is still set to true.
Which brings me to my question, which is as follows: is my APK still running in Dev mode or not? Or is it a peculiarity of Bugsnag, showing the error path like this? If not, how can I go about setting it to false?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For receiving more details: **where are you running your APK**? In device or in the simulator?

And have you tried installing directly on the device (**installing:** `cd android && ./gradlew installRelease && cd -` or **running:** `react-native run-android --configuration=release`)? Since it seems that you're running a dev version against localhost, although you've made an APK.

Also, you could send `__DEV__` as a property for Bugsnag to see whether it's true or false (in order to remove this chance of "peculiarity in Bugsnag").

Comment: I am indeed running on device. I have tried installing the APK through 'adb install -r path/to/apk' as well.
How do you suggest I send this property to Bugsnag? You kinda lost me there.

Comment: for instance: `this.client.notify(error, (report) => {
  report.inDevMode = __DEV__;
});` (see: https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/#attaching-custom-diagnostics)

Comment: When sending the error like this, the bundle path appears like so 'index.android.bundle:12 componentWillMount' Okay, now I'm confused.